# Save a value to Database - MVC

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to save a value in the "UserController" but I cannot seem tog et it to save to the database.

I can get the database value as stored in the UserController to change so that when the value is submitted and the view is refreshed it looks as though it was stored. (ie. changing from test to tested) However, as soon as I refresh the page again it returns to the previous value and the database shows no change throughout this.

UserController:

```
var g = httpPost.VanityUrl;

DB.ppUser_editUser(g);
```

ppUser_editUser in ppUser:

```
public ppUser ppUser_editUser(string personVanity)
    {
        ppUser user = SessionUser.LoggedInUser.Person;
        user.VanityUrl = personVanity;
        BaseDB.SubmitChanges();
        return user;
    }
```

EditProfile View:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.VanityUrl, "Edit your Custom Url:")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VanityUrl, new { maxlength = 15 })
</div>
```

BaseDB:

```
public partial class StudioKit_MVC3Repository : IDisposable
{
    private StudioKit_MVC3ModelsDataContext _BaseDB;
    public StudioKit_MVC3ModelsDataContext BaseDB
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BaseDB == null)
            {
                if (StudioKit_MVC3Config.EnvironmentDetail.Name == "Production")
                {
                    _BaseDB = new StudioKit_MVC3ModelsDataContext(StudioKit_MVC3Config.EnvironmentDetail.ConnectionString);
                }
                else
                {
                    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(StudioKit_MVC3Config.EnvironmentDetail.ConnectionString);
                    var conn = new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
                    _BaseDB = new StudioKit_MVC3ModelsDataContext(conn);
                }
            }

            return _BaseDB;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I figured out the problem. I was saving the value to the session user instance and not the actual database. I got rid of the method and in the controller I simply put:

```
ppUser check = DB.ppUser_GetUserByPersonID(model.cskPersonID);
check.VanityUrl = httpPost.VanityUrl;
DB.Save();
```

Comment: What is `BaseDB`? A context from EF4?

Comment: I added it in an edit but I can't say I really understand what is going on. This website will actually be pulling from 2 different databases, and I have taken it for granted in saving values to one database. This time I am submitting the changes to ppUser (table).

Comment: if its EF 4.1+ shoildnt it be `db.Savechanges();` ?

Comment: db.Savechanges(); doesn't seem to be a valid method that I can call upon.